# Adding url to string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, url

I have a script which prints letters one by one and everything works fine.  However, I have one big question: is there any way that I can print a string from an array that will be used as a link?  I'm trying to add href in many ways, but no success.  Can anyone give me a clue on how to do this ?

This is the script :

```
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var greeting = [
    'text that should be a link'
];
text.innerHTML = '<i>▮</i>';

(function greet() {
    if (greeting.length > 0 && greeting.length < 3) {
        text.insertBefore(document.createElement(' '), text.lastChild);
    }

    var line = greeting.shift();
    if (!line) {
        return;
    }

    line = line.split('');
    (function type() {
        var character = line.shift();
        if (!character) {
            return setTimeout(greet, 100);
        }

        text.insertBefore(document.createElement(character), text.lastChild);
        setTimeout(type, 20);
    }());
}());
```

Comment: You could do it in exactly the same way, but from where does the `href` come, should the `<a>` element be clickable at any point, or only after the complete string is present in the element?

Comment: I would love if i could set something like this in array '<a href="#">click</a>' but when I do this Its printing it as a normal text

Comment: Out of curiosity does that posted script work when you run it, for me it (rightly) generates errors when pasted into [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j7c64bdu/); could you post the working code that does as you describe?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/78mw1mfL/11 This is exactly same code as on my index.html not sure why on fiddle does not work

Comment: Look in your browser's developer tools ('F12' in most browsers); the JavaScript console will show the errors explaining what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will create the html anchor links:

```
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var greeting = [
    { url:'www.google.com', text: 'google' }  // an example of data.
];


(function greet() {
    if (greeting.length > 0 && greeting.length < 3) {
       var link = createLink(greeting[0].url,greeting[0].text);
       text.append(link);
    }

    function createLink(url, text) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.innerHTML = '<i>▮</i>';
        a.title = text;
        a.href = url;
        return a;
    }

    // rest of your code.

}());
```

Here is an example [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sc4catLv/)

Comment: Not Quite sure how I can combine it with my code beacuse when Im do it, im getting errors, This is how my script exactly look like: 
https://jsfiddle.net/78mw1mfL/11/
not sure why on fiddle its does not work but on localhost and on server works perfectly fine

Comment: How do you want to use the link? `<a>kbuild-dir := $(if $(filter /%,</a>` ?

Comment: By simply changing `document.createElement(' ')` to `document.createElement('a')` it "works", but are you wanting the array content inside the `<a></a>`?